# Move the temp upload directory in IIS

Tags: iis

So when uploading a file in .NET on IIS, the file is persisted temporarly to:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\*some generated folder*\uploads

Is it possible to configure this location?

C: is slow and uploads are faster than buffering to disk, so want to put the buffering to faster disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the compilation variable to a different folder.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s10awwz0(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: It appears the tempDirectory attribute applies to uploads also. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/viag/2006/10/25/how-to-change-the-default-tempfile-upload-location-for-the-asp-net-2-0-fileupload-control/